# Angularjs & bootstrap Datepicker, disable dates dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I need to implement the following:

2 Datepickers with 2 consecutive months. The user can select a start- and an end-date.

Here is the tricky part that I can't figure out:

After selecting the start date I must enable/disable various dates.

From what I understand the disabled date are only fired once and the min-max only lets me select one range. However I need to disable/enable a multitude of dates.

I am very new to angular so I can't quite make heads or tails of the source yet.

I hope this is clear enough.

Also open to suggestions for a different datepicker directive that let's me do this. (Needs to able to default to open)

Comment: It's not. Maybe a jsfiddle?

Comment: since there is no official angular datepicker, it is anyone's guess what directive you are using

Comment: This is a regular datepicker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ata3YOsl7p9hVNMRQFGT?p=preview

After clicking on the 8th I need to disable the 12th, 16th, 20th-26th

for example and then the user can select another date out of what's left enabled

Comment: I hope this is clear enough now. I have been banging my head at this for a few days now.

Comment: Have you read this? https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/779

Comment: Thanks! I have seen a few issues but not this one. I tried playing around with it but couldn't figure out how to trigger refreshView.